# Terminating a path on specific node types

Tags: neo4j, operators, cypher

I have something like *Project->Organisation->Project*.  so one organization can have many projects.  I want to query starting with a specific project, and return all nodes associated with the project (including organisations) *except* for other projects.  so I wrote this malfunctioning query:

```
match (p:Project {Code: 'XR-1'})-[r*1..3]-(n) where not(n:Project) return p, n, r
```

which parses (to my understanding) as: find project XR-1 and get all nodes within 3 layers of depth that are not projects.  what I'm getting is a bunch of other projects.  it finds the organization that runs XR-1 and since that org also runs a bunch of other projects, it returns those.

what is the correct way to write this?

*** Update I ***
I've come to the realisation that the where clause is greedy i.e. it gets applied to the longest matching pattern, instead of the shortest.  so if I do something like:

```
match (p:Project {Code: 'XR-1'})-[r*1..3]-(n) 
where labels(n)[0] in ['Documentation'] return p, n, r
```

it returns projects run by the organization that runs XR-1 because they have a documentation node.  it matches on the documentation node and fails to filter out organisations and projects.  it's greedy.  so what I need is a way to apply the where clause to *every* node found on the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this query work for you?

```
MATCH p=(proj:Project { Code: 'XR-1' })-[r*1..3]-(n)
WITH proj, RELATIONSHIPS(p) AS rs, TAIL(NODES(p)) AS ns
WHERE NONE (x IN ns WHERE x:Project)
RETURN proj, ns, rs;
```

It filters out paths that contain any extra `Project` nodes.

See [this console](http://console.neo4j.org/r/o8id1i) for an example of this query working.

Comment: good learning stuff for me there.  thanks.  and yes, it works